# Junk character is not visible in Oracle SQL developer

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I am not able to view a junk character in Oracle SQL developer, but it is visble in PLSQL developer. Below screenshot is from PLSQL developer:

[image]

Below is the screenshot from Oracle SQL developer:

[image]

The junk character is visible in notepad too but not visible here. 
Please explain how can it be made visible in Oracle SQL developer as this is the only tool I am allowed to use officially.

Comment: You can use the dump function to see the character encoding - "select dump(name) from ..."  Other than that you may have a different character set in the database vs. the client app?

Comment: @OldProgrammer, I got the following result using the dump function
`Typ=1 Len=45: 82,65,71,72,85,78,65,84,72,32,68,65,68,65,32,77,65,71,68,85,77,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,2`
Also please exaplain what do you mean by `Other than that you may have a different character set in the database vs. the client app?`

Comment: So the last character in the string result is an ASCII code of 2. How it got in there is something you need to figure out.

Comment: @OldProgrammer, this data is migrated data, so it is possible that incorrect data has come through migration; but my point is why can't I see it in Oracle SQL developer? As I could not see it, a lot of unnecessary time was wasted to find it out.

Comment: I don't see any preferences to allow that.

Comment: In order to see the STX (ASCII 2) character you will have to use OS tools.  You can get hexdump for windows, or use the UNIX od command.  Spool the the output to a file or screen scrape the output and place in a file with an editor.  And I believe that STX is used to mark the start of text in some non-Latin character locales.  Check the locale (NLS or language) setting carefully on your desktop.  It should match the oracle setting. You can also use sqlplus dump as @oldprogrammer noted.

Comment: @jimmcnamara, Thanks for the valuable input. Can you please guide me how to check the NLS setting in IBM-AIX? (I believe I should check with settings from the OS where DB is installed i.e. IBM AIX instead of my local Windows 7 OS)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `locale` command:

```
$ jim>  locale
LANG=C
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_CTYPE="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_ALL=
```

Usual locale setting on our DB servers == `UTF-8`  If you use non-Latin characters in in your language it will be different.